# Juggernaut environment config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, juggernaut

I'm trying to figure out how to run Juggernaut server in production – assuming that I would be able to configure different ports for the server in the development and production environment, because I can't control the port in my production environment. And also assuming that the server would be to start in "detached" mode?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the process further I realize that since the server needs to be started up with a config file specified, I can just have different config files for different environments. The only question remains, if the server needs to be started up in a "detached" mode or how that works...

Comment: Just found some Capistrano recipes that look like they will probably answer my question: http://github.com/nesquena/cap-recipes

Comment: just to mention that Juggernaut has been deprecated see http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are planning to continue using Juggernaut despite deprecation, getting it up and running is fairly straightforward - you can just use the instructions on the github page using npm and they work pretty well. The Juggernaut CLI script lets you configure a port, so no problem there either.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout forever.  It makes backgrounding javascript apps pretty simple... https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever